# How to restore a physical volume without the restore file?

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

I previously created a logical volume from a volume group containing 4 physical volumes (4 SATA disks). 
 Then, my linux crashed so I had to reinstall the linux system, and I didn't have any important files so I reset the whole computer without keeping any data. 
 Now, I want to recover my volume group, but I accidentally performed pvcreate a second time on one of the four disks.
 I realized the mistake and pvremoved the new pvcreated disk.
Now when I perform vgcfgrestore, I get this:

```
$ vgcfgrestore VG
  Couldn't find device with uuid jpCLfx-oEyt-MC8s-cGb6-oef2-Qrde-N5bUlr.
  Cannot restore Volume Group VG with 1 PVs marked as missing.
  Restore failed.
```

I figured out that I can restore the missing disk with pvcreate and the indicated uuid.
 Except that I lost the restore file when resetting the whole linux system. 
 I think it's supposed to be in /etc/lvm, but now I only have:

```
$ ls /etc/lvm/
backup/   profile/
```

And lvm tells me that the restore file is required for what I'm trying to do.

```
$ pvcreate --uuid "jpCLfx-oEyt-MC8s-cGb6-oef2-Qrde-N5bUlr" /dev/sdd
  --restorefile is required with --uuid
  Run `pvcreate --help' for more information.
```

What should I do now?